# File blocked file after JAXB unmarshal error

Tags: java, file, exception, jaxb, unmarshalling

I have a JAXB marshall/unmarshall process that works fine, except for this: sometimes the files I have to unmarshall are empty or not well-formatted so the unmarshall throws an Exception. This is ok, but after this exception, the file I´m unmarshalling (source xml File java object) gets blocked. I can´t use it.

I have noticed this trying to delete or rename the file right after the unmarshall exception. If no exception happens, the files can be used with no problem, as it should.

Is there any way to "unblock" this files? I think there has to be any way to release, close or liberate the resources of the JAXB context or unmarshaller object that have blocked my file.

Thanks in advance,

Dani

Comment: Posting your code would help us better understand your problem. I would be interested to see what you're doing after you catch the Exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing the resource liberation (closing streams, etc.) in the finally block. Noob error many years ago! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You could create a `FileInputStream` from your file and then unmarshal that.  Then you have greater control over what happens when an error occurs.

```
FileInputStream inputStram = new FileInputStream(file);
Foo foo = (Foo) Unmarshaller unmarshal(inputStream);
```